# Find Class attribute using JQuery "removeAttr"

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-1.9

I want remove text-align attribute from a class using Jquery

for example:

CSS

```
.main{ text-align:left; padding:10px;}
```

HTML.

```
<h2 id="abc" class="main">
 <div id="xyz"></div>
</h2>
```

Using `xyz` id, How can I remove text-align attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$("#xyz").parent().css({'text-align': "initial"});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no styles for `#xyz` so you have to get the `parent` first:

```
$("#xyz").parent().css('padding', 0);
```

If you want to remove the entire class you might use `removeClass`:

```
$("#xyz").parent().removeClass("main");
```

Comment: I want use removeAttr() in jquery

Comment: @AmitAgrawal `removeAttr()` can only be used to remove HTML attributes. Not to remove CSS properties.

Comment: @arulmr - How can I remove Css Properties inside the class

Comment: @AmitAgrawal CSS properties cannot be removed using jQuery. Instead you can assign a null value to them.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
var ix=$("#xyz").closest('h2').attr("id")
$("#"+ix+".main").css('text-align', "initial");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `text-align` style rule is not given through an html attribute. It is set via a css rule.

If you want to change the style of `#xyz`, the simplest way is to add a rule in your css stylesheet :

```
.main{ text-align:left;padding:10px;}
#xyz {text-align: right}
```

or use an extra class (if you need to apply it to several items) :

```
.main{ text-align:left;padding:10px;}
.right-aligned {text-align: right}
```

Using jQuery, what you can do is add a `style` attribute with another `text-align` rule, which will override the css rule :

```
$('#xyz').css('text-align', 'right');
```